# Is there a way to escape resolve alias in webpack imports?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

Using Vue-CLI 3, here's my some.scss file:

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
```

Causes an error with paths, because "~" references to `node_modules` and "@" references to a "src" directory, since "@fortawesome" uses "@" sign in the module name, i cannot correctly import it. Is there a way to tell webpack, that it's not an alias, but a module name?

Posting Vue-CLI's 3 webpack config:

[image]

Comment: @import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome'; have you tries this?

Comment: "@" is mapped to "src" directory.

Comment: You are saying, that, "@" is mapped to "src" directory. Can you post configuration, where it is done? `@` in fortawesome package is standard syntax for scoped package: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope

Comment: I don't think, you can make this work. IMO with that alias you are trying to do something like "to override the standard keyword" (the `@` of scoped package in this case). I suggest to remove that alias, or if you insist on it, you can try to write your issue on the webpack github. Maybe they will implement ignoring use of aliases for this case (although I doubt it).